# Crystal Reports: Set date parameter value to calculation without using a sub-report?

Tags: crystal-reports, default-value, commandparameter

Is it possible to set the value of a command parameter to a date calculation i.e 2 months from the date run without putting it in a sub-report and passing the values from a main report?

[image: Default Date value of Command Parameter in Crystal Reports]

Comment: couldn't understand... do you mean hardcoding the values in query?

Comment: Like setting the value to two months after the run date in a formula

Comment: Can you show example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either using a subreport or in the calling application. No other way. You can check this video to see how it works in an application:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_RTagAndBOE.aspx

Jump directly to 2:12 or select  "Parameter templates" in the menu. This software has a free version, which supports the default values so if changing the application is an option for you go and get it from here: 
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx

If you developed your own application you can implement similar interface.